# SQL - Why I need to cast as decimal?

Tags: sql, teradata, decimalformat, variable-types

[image]I am doing an SQL exercise  when I have to sum up and split by 100. I have gotten what I wanted (Variable TOTAL_AMT) but I would like to understand better why TOTAL_AMT1 is not right:

In the output when the TOTAL_AMT is small like 0.1, TOTAL_AMT1 just bring 0.0. Why is this?

```
'SELECT
Extract (YEAR From CREATED_AT) AS YEAR_NO
,Extract (MONTH From CREATED_AT) AS MONTH_NO
,CURRENCY_ID
,  Cast((Sum(AMOUNT )/100) AS DECIMAL(6,1)) AS TOTAL_AMT1
,(Sum(Cast(AMOUNT AS DECIMAL(6,1)))/100) AS TOTAL_AMT
FROM DDEWA03P.DW36991_SALES
GROUP BY  1,2,3
ORDER BY YEAR_NO,MONTH_NO,CURRENCY_ID ASC;'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do it in another order, `CAST(SUM(AMOUNT) as DECIMAL(6,1)) / 100`

Comment: Because integer / integer returns only the integer part of the result.

Comment: thanks @jarlh . That works as well. My question here would be why exactly TOTAL_AMT1 way would not give the right number. Is it something about variables type?

Comment: As I said, the decimal part is lost when you do integer division. You have to force decimal division to get the decimals too.

Comment: Thanks!! man! :) answered

Answer (score 1):

It's due to rounding errors. Consider the following:

```sql
select cast(sum(amount) as decimal(6,1))
from (values (0.04), (0.04), (0.04)) example(amount)
```

The above sums 0.04, 0.04 and 0.04 to get 0.12, which it then casts to 0.1.

Now consider this:

```sql
select sum(cast(amount as decimal(6,1)))
from ( values (0.04), (0.04), (0.04) ) example(amount)
```

This casts 0.04, 0.04 and 0.04 to 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 and sums them to get 0.0.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think amount too small if you cast it to Decimal first, sum all of it will be very small than sum amount then cast it to decimal